# How to count number of connected roads in OSMnx python package

Tags: python, networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx

Is it possible to count the number of connected roads (edges) for each road within an OSM network and also delineate by type of road? For example road A is connected to 2 major roads and 3 minor roads.

I attempted to attempted to add a 0.5 metre buffer to each road within the network and count the number of interestions and split the results by road type, however this some roads with no connected roads, whcih is not possible given it is part of the road network, whereby there must be a minimum of 1 other road connected.